# Placing item at first nil element in column of 2D matrix

Tags: lisp

So I'm making a relatively simple game using Lisp.

I create a board with of specified size with all NIL elements:

```
(defun make-board(rows columns) 
  (cond ((= rows 1) (list (make-list columns)))
        (t ( append (list (make-list columns)) (make-board (1- rows) columns)))))
```

Now I'm working on place function that will place a value at the first NIL element in the column of the 2D list:

```
(defun place(player column matrix)
    ;need some help here

    ;I can get the specified column, is there a better way?!
    (let (col)(get-column column matrix))
)
```

I can retrieve a specified column:

```
; return the given column
(defun get-column 
   (colnum matrix)
   (mapcar (lambda (row) (nth colnum row)) matrix))
```

I feel like this is simple, but Lisp is not working well with me unfortunately. I also prefer this implementation without iteration since that is the "proper" way to do Lisp.

Edit:

For clarification, make-board will return something like the following:

```
(make-board 5 5)
((NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL) 
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL) 
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL) 
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
 (NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL))
```

Comment: Why is it tagged 'Emacs'? Is the code in Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why recursivity should be the "proper" way to program in Lisp. The loop macro is extremely useful, and functions like the one you want to implement can be easily achieved with it.

```
(defun make-board(rows columns)
  (loop repeat rows collect
    (loop repeat columns collect nil)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it would be more convenient to use a two-dimensional array for your board:

```
(defun make-board (rows columns)
  (make-array (list rows columns)
              :initial-element nil))
```

In order to find the first null cell of a column, loop over that column:

```
(defun find-null-cell-index (column board)
  "Returns the row index of the first cell in the given column of the board
that contains nil."
  (loop :for i :below (array-dimension board 0)
        :when (null (aref board i column))
        :do (return-from find-null-cell-index i)))
```